# no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'const QString' to 'QTreeWidgetItem'

Tags: c++, c++11, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I am building a small application using `QTreeWidgetItem` and `QTreeWidgetItem` for practicing them and for practicing how to best and where use them. This is a small application where I am trying to assign an icon to a `QTreeWidget` using a helper function.
Now for some reasons I get the following error :

`no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'const QString' to 'QTreeWidgetItem'`,
below the code:

**mainwindow.h**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    QTreeWidgetItem *createItem(const QString &name, const QString &iconPath);

    QString name() const {
        return m_Name;
    }

    QString iconPath() const {
        return m_Path;
    }

    void setName(const QString &name)
    {
        m_Name = name;
    }

    void setPath(const QString &path)
    {
        m_Path = path;
    }

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QString m_Name;
    QString m_Path;
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    auto *top1 = createItem("Images", "/path/to/icon.png");
    auto *top2 = createItem("Path", "/path/to/icon.png");
    top1->addChild(createItem("Original", "/path/to/icon.png"));
    top1->addChild(createItem("Sample", "/path/to/icon.png"));
    
    top2->addChild(createItem("Left Side", "/path/to/icon.png"));
    top2->addChild(createItem("Right Side", "/path/to/icon.png"));

    ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItems({ top1, top2 });
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


QTreeWidgetItem *MainWindow::createItem(const QString &name, const QString &iconPath)
{
    auto *item = QTreeWidgetItem(name);  // <-- Error Here
    item.setIcon(0, QIcon(iconPath));
    return item;
}
```

Now this is a compiler error and it seems that the constructor is missing `QTreeWidgetItem` and therefore is preventing me from using the helper function I created to help me define name and path for the small icon.
I researched the problem and came across [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60342999/no-matching-conversion-for-functional-style-cast-from-int-to-itemtype) and also I read the [additional source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505861/function-style-cast-vs-constructor).

Thanks for helping me shedding light on this issue.

Comment: There is indeed [no `QTreeWidgetItem` constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html) that takes a `QString`. What did you mean to achieve with `QTreeWidgetItem(name)`? You may be looking for `auto* item = new QTreeWidgetItem({name});`  (this uses a constructor taking `QStringList`). Also, since `item` is a pointer, make it `item->setIcon(...)`

Comment: Thanks for your timr @IgorTandetnik it works! :) Can I ask you to please clarify the difference between `QTreeWidgetItem(name)` and `QTreeWidgetItem({name})` ? Also if you would like to amswer to the question offically I can accept it! Thanks for your time! very much appreciated!

Comment: The latter is a shorthand for `QTreeWidgetItem(QStringList{name})`

Comment: Ohhh ok! I got you now! Thanks :)